# CS GO command change weaponed hand

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have seen people in some videos changing weapons from right hand to left hand. I know that this is a console command, but I dont know what the command is. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**cl_righthand 1** - Right hand
**cl_righthand 0** - Left hand

```
in console
bind "keyname" "cl_righthand 1" <hit enter>
then
bind "keyname" "cl_righthand 0" <hit enter>
```

Change keyname to whichever key you want to perform that action.

Alternatively you can use

```
bind KEY "toggle cl_righthand 0 1"
```

to have the switch on the same button.

Comment: Okey, this is the command, and what i need to do when i press a key the command execute?

Comment: @AndoniAlda Check edit.

Comment: You can also use autoexec.cfg, `cl_righthand`.

Answer (score 0):

Example: If you want to switch weapons from 1 hand to another on the key "Z" you type this in console:

Bind z "toggle cl_righthand 0 1"

After binding it:
If you press "Z" once it goes to the lefthand, if you press again it goes to the righthand.